# Am 23 applying for a EEA family permit in Spain

Tags: family

I am 23 years and we live together so no prove of sendind money to me but his residence number is at the back of mine residence permit.I submitted both my fathers I'd and my brothers I.d since they are both EEA nationals.we will be going together so I did not show any tenancy agreement but gave my junior brother house address in the UK.
Supporting documents I sent..
My fathers I.D
My brothers I.D
House contract showing my name and my brothers plus my dad.
Bank book of my fathers transaction and monthly pay.
Spanish residence I.d show the same address with my dad.
My fathers passport copy with mine.
Pay slips of my father four months.
I did not include accommodation in the UK sinse my dad will be going with me.
My dad niho letter and number because he went to the UK and applied for it and came back.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your question. Where are you now? UK? And you all want to move to Spain? Or the other way around (in Spain now, moving to UK)? What is your citizenship? Do you want the permit to move permanently or for a visit?

Comment: You are only eligible for an EEA family permit if you can show that you are a member of your father's household.  But it seems that you have already applied, so unless you've received a refusal (have you?), there's not much we can do to help.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am 23 but my question is,is accommodation part of the requirements or no.

Comment: Because my father just went for his ninho number and came back we are now planning to move there,I only filled it with my junior brother's address he is currently there working.

Answer (score -1):

EEA family permit is what it is called in the UK. In Schengen countries it's a little different.

For Spain you would have to show that you're dependent on them.

See this page:
[Registering your non-EU family members in another EU country – Spain](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/residence/documents-formalities/non-eu-family-members-residence-card/spain/index_en.htm)

Comment: I just got a refusal letter stating,I did not provide financial dependency,that is money transferred into my accounts. But we both live in the same house,how is that possible.

Comment: @kwamenabilson are you moving from Spain to the UK or from the UK to Spain?

Comment: Spain to UK with my father

Comment: My junior brother is already there and my father was waiting for my visa to go with me but I got a refusal,please can I go with him by road.

Comment: @kwamenabilson That is risky.  I don't know how effective the computer system at Dover is, but they *ought* to be able to note that you have just had a visa refused, and turn you away.

Comment: So I should not try it or I can give it a try with my father, please I need ur advise.

Comment: @kwamena bilson You are 23 years old, of working age and no longer a minor,  it seems they want to see proof that your father supports you financially over and above the fact that you live in his house. You should edit your question to include the full refusal reason. The refusal will be on record. If you try to enter by road you may well face a very difficult and stressful Immigration interview or, worse, be denied entry.

Comment: In Spain there is no work am not working but stays with my father.my father cannot transfer money into my accounts because he gives me money by hand so how can I prove that.The refusal says I need to show proof of financial support.

Comment: @Traveller a dependent child qualifies as an immediate family member.  An independent child who is a member of the household qualifies as an extended family member.  It may be necessary to emphasize this in a new application.  An appeal might also be successful, depending on the exact nature of the refusal.

Comment: @kwamenabilson please scan your refusal letter, black out the identifying information, and edit your question to include the image.  Life-on-mars: you may want to consider editing this answer now that it is definitively established that the goal here is to apply in Spain for a family permit to go to the UK.

Comment: @MartinBonner for spouses we have some evidence that officers at the ferries or trains are quite willing to identify family permit refusals as ridiculously improper and therefore admit the spouse.  I would be more cautious here, though, since it probably concerns an "extended family member" (given the lack of evidence of financial dependence).

Comment: @Phoog I agree, but given the OP’s age and lack of evidence of financial dependence, how do they overcome the guidance that states extended family members are not guaranteed to get a permit? https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/eea-family-permit

Comment: I want to re apply but how can I prove financial dependency. Should my father transfer money into my accounts or what.

Comment: @Traveller I'm not sure.  Perhaps there's more information about how that decision is made in the guidance for ECOs, but I don't have time to look at it just now.

Comment: @phoog I think the point here is not even how to get an EEA family permit in the UK. It's rather what is the concept of dependency in this context and how to prove it to the satisfaction of the UK immigration authorities.